# Parametrisation of curve

Tags: analysis, curves

If there exist $f: [a,b]\rightarrow R^2$ 1-1 C^1 map for some $a<b$.

And if there exist $g:[c,d]\rightarrow Im(f)$ C^1 map, will $g$ be 1-1 map?

such that $g(c) = f(a)$ and $g(d) = f(b)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.

**Example**. Take any one-to-one $C^1$-function $f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R^2$. Then the $C^1$-function

$$g:[0,3\pi]\to\Bbb R^2,\quad g(t)= f(-\cos t)$$

starts at $g(0)=f(-1)$ and ends at $g(3\pi)=f(1)$ but is not one-to-one (because it is not injective).

---

I think the problem gets much harder when we claim that $g$ is injective (no self-intersection) and we only have to show that it is surjective (onto).

Comment: I edited question a little bit

Comment: @Sushil I edited my answer.

Comment: I asked for f being 1-1

Comment: @Sushil Fixed it.

Comment: will it turn out to be onto in latter case?

Comment: @Sushil I thought about it a bit. Probably it will, but I cannot give a proof (yet). There may be very crazy non-self-intersecting curves.

Comment: actually I am trying to find some kind of equivalence relation on curves so that non self intersecting curve lies only in 2 equivalence classes, if possible. Like this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648757

Answer (score 0):

let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ be defined by $f(t)=(t,t)$. Then $f$ is $C^1$ and $1-1$ .

Now consider $g:[-1,1] \to Im(f)$ , defined by $g(t)=(t^2,t^2)$. $g$ is $C^1$ but not $1-1$ .

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention important condition

Comment: In my example we have $f'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ !!

Comment: yes but sorry I want one condition which is same starting and same endpoints