# Reparametrization of A non intersecting curve

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, curves

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$. If there exist a one-to-one map $f: [a,b]\rightarrow A$ such that $f$ is $C^1$. And we define equivalence relation on set of all C^1 function from $[a,b]$ to $A$ as two functions being equivalent if there exist diffeomorphism of $[a,b]$ on $[a,b]$ mapping $a$ to $a$ and $b$ to $b$ such that diagram we get bewteen commutes. How many different kind of equivalence classes will exist?

$\gamma_1 : [a,b]\longrightarrow A$

$\gamma_2: [a,b]\longrightarrow A$

Now $A$ to $A$, there is identity map and for equivalwnce we want map from $[a,b]$ to $[a,b]$

Comment: I edited your question slightly. One-to-one already implies "onto" (so I removed it). Can you show the diagram that should commute? I am not sure which one you are talking about.

Comment: don't know much programming but wrote something, I think it give some idea to you what I want to convey @M.Winter

Comment: Sorry I meant equivalence classes and not equivalence relations. @M.Winter

Comment: What should the second sentence mean? I see no implication of this sentence for the rest of the question. And is the equivalence relation defined on all *one-to-one* $C^1$ function? My guess would be that there is one equivalence class. But a proof might be hard. E.g. can there be an injective curve with the units square $[0,1]^2$ as image?